# Duplicate entry error, while using entityManager.persist() for 1 to many relationship

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, one-to-many

I have a JPA Entity A that has a @OneToMany to another JPA entity B.
Again JPA Entity B has a @OneToMany to another JPA entity C.

Persist() method works fine when there are:
1 A-> 1 B -> n C.

But throws an error:
`Duplicate entry '8009' for key 'UK_q47kn3f84och96oi9q58optr0'`,
when there are
1 A-> n B -> n C.

The primary key is ID, which is an auto-generated field.
I have added  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) for ID.

The error is for a duplicate ID, I am not able to resolve the issue as ID is an auto-generated field.

Can you please help me on this?

Comment: Can you check on which colum UK_q47kn3f84och96oi9q58optr0 is?

Comment: I am not sure, I did not create such a column. Not sure how this column is popping up from

Comment: This is the name of a Unique Key that Hibernate generated. Please have a look at the database and check which column must be unique in the unique constraint

Comment: Are there any cascades defined on the fields? Please post the entities in question